# Language Resource file not found: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle

Tags: java

I am trying to get past a hurdle with my application. Seems that my code is have a problem finding the resource bundle. Error reads Language Resource file not found: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key Login. yes I am using "resource/login" but the resource files are login.properties, login_en_us.properties, etc. is there anything to reference to get better information for intelliJ 2022.2.1? I am having a hard time finding anything. I am trying to figure out What java is looking for or how it trying to locate the properties file.

Thank you for the help.

Error: Language Resource file not found: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key Login

Line of code in question

...
`rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Language/Login", Locale.getDefault());`
...

my directory structure is as follows...

[Resource application directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eywnM.png)

Comment: have you tried moving the rss bundle out of the language package

Comment: The exception message says that you are trying to look up the *key* Login *within* the resource bundle. This is about the *content* of your resource bundle.